# "[Error] invalid branch to/from an OpenMP structured block" I have this error

Tags: search, tree, binary, openmp

```
struct dugum* ara(struct dugum* kok,int aranacakSayi)
{
    double start; 
    double end; 
    start = omp_get_wtime(); 
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) shared(start,end,aranacakSayi) private(i)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
        { 
           printf("\n Kontrol edilen sayilar : %d Thread : %d \n \n",kok->sayi,omp_get_thread_num());
    
           if(kok->sayi==aranacakSayi || kok ==NULL  ){
              end = omp_get_wtime(); 
              printf("Calisma zamani %f saniye \n", end - start);
              return kok; 
          }
                
          if (aranacakSayi > kok->sayi) 
             kok = kok->sag;    
         else if (aranacakSayi < kok->sayi) 
             kok = kok->sol;    
       }
    }
}
```

I am trying inorder travesal with openMP  I have this error. Code isnt returned "return kok" is take some errors.
I need help to fix this error This is about openMP structered  block.

Comment: sorry its search function 
I typed wrong

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `return` from inside a parallel region... (Think about it. How are all of the threads supposed to know that one of them wants to return?)

Comment: Technically speaking, you can use OpenMP cancellation, but you have to have a fairly good reason to do so given the overhead.

Comment: @HristoIliev true. But,  as you say, it s unlikely to be a not a performant solution! (Especially if this code is really what the user wants, since it's doing only ns of work inside there!)

Comment: So how can i parallelize this code with openmp ?  
can you help me a little bit ?

Comment: struct dugum* ara(struct dugum* kok,int aranacakSayi)
{
 double start; 
double end; 
start = omp_get_wtime(); 
 
 if(kok != NULL)
 printf("\n Kontrol edilen sayilar : %d \n",kok->sayi);
 

 if(kok->sayi==aranacakSayi || kok ==NULL  )
    return kok;
 

 if(aranacakSayi<kok->sayi)
 ara(kok->sol,aranacakSayi);
 else
 ara(kok->sag,aranacakSayi);
 
 end = omp_get_wtime(); 
printf("Calisma zamani %f saniye\n", end - start);
 
}
 I need to parallelize this code

Comment: If that is your real code there is likely no point in attempting to parallelise it since there is almost no work in there. If this is an educational exercise, then say so...